# IPad and Openframeworks

Tags: ipad, interactive, openframeworks

Can someone point me in the right direction to learning how to use Openframeworks to develop and IPad app.  Perhaps some good tutorials, I can't seem to find any good documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs of openFrameworks is quite outdated. But you can discover OF through the examples. Just download the iPhone package here: http://www.openframeworks.cc/download and follow the instructions in the included readme. I think a good start is, try to get the examples running on your device and start to modify the examples. If you have any further questions, the people here --> http://forum.openframeworks.cc/ will be happy to help you out.
For a more in-depth discover of openFrameworks, look at the inofficial doxygen docs here --> http://ofxfenster.undef.ch/doc/

Answer (score 3):

Getting OF running on iPad is actually pretty much the same thing as running on iphone.
have you got it running before?
if you haven’t, first thing is you need to pay Apple $99 if you want to run it on real device, 
otherwise it’s free to try on the simulator.
there is some instructions on OF site for the first run, 
just go through it these complicated stuffs only need to be done once:
http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/iphone/
(the guide is totally not updated at all, but it’s pretty much the same process with minor UI difference)

Any iOS OF example should runs on iPad the same way as iPhone does.
but to get iPad native resolution, you’ll have to change it manually.
it's in Application>General and in Deployment Info change the Devices drop down to iPad. (screenshot attached)

try it with any iOS examples
and if you want to put any code for mac version, 
just make a copy of any iOS example and hand paste the code in appropriate void, 
they are pretty much the same except mouse event vs touch event. 
which a bit different in logic but just play around with it. not too hard to get used to.
basically touch events are touch.x/touch.y instead of mouseX mouseY. 
(and touch events are private to each void so you might need other variables to pass it somewhere else)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a forum link but there was an openframeworks forum question on this just last week and folks posted a number of sites that have good examples/tutorials. Here's one on doing pixel operations for graphic effects:

http://itp.nyu.edu/varwiki/Syllabus/Pixels-S10